# Generating a table that progresses vertically

Tags: php, html-table

I am currently generating a table in the following manner:

```
A0 A1 A2 A3
B0 B1 B2 B3
C0 C1 C2 C3
D0 D1 D2 D3
```

I'd like to do:

```
A0 B0 C0 D0
A1 B1 C1 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
A3 B3 C3 D3
```

So basically make it progress vertically with 4 columns.

Current code:

```
<table cellspacing="2px">
    <?php

      # display products in 4 column table #

        $i=0;
        while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if($i > 0 and $i % 4 == 0) {
                echo '<tr></tr>';
            }

        //passing id in link to retrieve product details
        echo '<td><a href="displayProduct.php?product_id='.$data['product_id'].'" class="myButton">'.$data['name'].'</a></td>';
        $i++;   
        }

    ?>
</table>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

### Clarification

In the illustration above, I'm merely pointing out that I'd like to have the result progress vertically down and it also needs to expand to 4 columns (I've only shown 2 however it needs to expand to 4).

In the code snippet it progresses horizontally.

I have also updated the question to keep it simple.

I hope that clears any ambiguity.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want it to have 4 columns, why do you show only 2 columns in "I'd like to do"?

Comment: This question unfortunately doesn't make a lot of sense. (I didn't down vote you btw) You say you want a 13 x 4 table and then show an example of a 2 x N example...

Comment: Added some notes to clarify my question.

Comment: @Barmar: Can you please un-downvote my question if the clarification provided has improved the clarity of my question.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
<table>
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        if ($i > 0) {
            // End last row unless this is the first row
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        // Start a new row
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo '<td>...</td>';
    $i++;
}
if ($i > 0) {
    // Close out the last row, unless there wasn't any data
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

You had `<tr></tr>` backwards -- if you want to end one row and start a new one, it must be `</tr><tr>`. But the first row needs to be treated specially, since there's no previous row to end. If you know there will always be data, you can output the first `<tr>` and last `</tr>` unconditionally as part of the HTML code, but I wrote my code defensively.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my code, however I need to the results to appear vertically. Any suggestion on how can achieve this? (please see my clarification section for more info)

Comment: AFAIK, tables are always displayed with horizontal rows. You need to rearrange the data to display in the order you want. You can fetch all the data into an array, then iterate through it in steps of `count($array)/4`.

Answer (score 0):

Meh... who uses TABLES anymore? Do it with CSS! Very Easily done. Adjust my sample as needed.

```
<?
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$count = 0;
$total = 100; // whatever your total is from sql result;
while ($count < $total) {
echo '<img src="foldername/'.$itempic[$count].'" style=\'postion:absolute;top:'.$y.'px;left:'.$x.'px;\'>'."\n";
$y = $y + 50;
if ($y > 300){
$y = 0;
$x = $x + 50;
}
$count++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example I made specifically for you:
Yes it is a bit gimp, but the logic is what you can glean from it and adjust it to your needs.
It does work though, I just wasn't going to take the time to make an example perfect.

```
<?
$info = Array(
A0,A1,A2,A3,
B0,B1,B2,B3,
C0,C1,C2,C3,
D0,D1,D2,D3);


$count = 0;
$total = 20;
$row = 0;
$col = 0;
while ($count < $total){
    echo $info[$col+$row];
$col++;
$row = $row +3;
    if($col > 4){
$col = 0;
$row = $row - 14;
echo '<br/>';}
$count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a swirl and get back to you.